# Writing tests for code compiled for Microchip's PIC 16f series - Need a Simulator written in Java

Tags: java, microcontroller, simulator, pic, microchip

I'm looking for a way to write tests in Java for behaviour of a 16F microcontroller, given compiled code.

I have looked for something written in Java that simulates the PIC microcontrollers, but found nothing.

I want to write Java that represents other hardware that the microcontroller will eventually be interfaced with so I can thoroughly test the design.

Are there any? Preferably open source?

Thanks

Comment: *"Preferably open source?"*  By 'open source' do you actually mean 'free'?  Important distinction.

Comment: Free for personal use to be specific!

Answer (score 0):

A simple [Google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=PIC%2016F%20chip%20simulator) turned up [this site](http://www.picemulator.com/links.html).  At least one of the simulators is Java and downloadable.